# Error with PNG files extracted from iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, png, pngcrush

I extracted a photo folder from an iPhone app but all the PNG files in the folder are not viewable. I tried googling it up and then tried few apps that fix PNGs from iPhone, but none of them worked. One app even said that my files were NOT in PNG format, does anyone know how to fix this?

here is the photo folder for reference:  https://www.mediafire.com/?zk8339l4ik7vg3d or http://file.groovincat.com/files/tara/s3/alarm/photo/data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search StackOverflow for "pngcrush xcode" and you'll find plenty of information about this problem.  Basically, your files were crushed with a modified version of pngcrush distributed by Apple in violation of the license, that turns PNG images into something that is not in PNG format (the first chunk isn't IHDR, pixels are ARGB instead of RGBA, and are premultiplied).  There are various applications for reversing the effect, turning your images back into PNG format (e.g., "pngdefry" or Apple's pngcrush itself).